# Is there any functionality for dropping on particular rowindex ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have used ag-grid-angular and i need to drop data on grids particular row.
For example: If there is list and from that list i want to drag data and drop on ag-grid's particular index. is there any way to get rowIndex on which we are droppping data?

Comment: welcome to [so], please go through how to create [mcve] to help others answer your question

Comment: check the row node section in ag-grid - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-node/

Comment: @koolhuman i need a row index when mouse enter on perticular row. There is a event MouseEnter but thats's also not working. do you have any idea about MouseEnter event? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PoonamThote - I have added code below which shows the move over event and displays rowIndex in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below plunker which displays the rowIndex value in the console on hover of any cell in the ag-grid.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Bt4f0LP4wtluhxnbJ4Af?p=preview

```
this.gridOptions.onCellMouseOver = function(params){
  console.log(params.rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. let me explain my scenario. See in my application there is a list on one side and i want drag list data and drop on grid's particular row index. if i'll use the above event then it ll give me the row index but if the mouse move after dropping it ll give me another row indexes and it will goes on..
i only want the row index when i drop the dragged data on particular row.

Comment: @PoonamThote which event are you using to drop data on ag-grid row. Could you please put your code in plunker?